# VB 2010 - Datagridview displaying a column as a sub row

Tags: vb.net, winforms, data-binding, datagridview

I'm trying to display one particular column as a sub-row from a table - how do i do it within a DataGridView?

The code i have so far is below and this correctly populates the DataGridView from the MySQL script. However, I would like to take the last column 'in_race_comment' and make that appear below the other columns as a sub-row, stretched across the entire datagridview so it has a whole row to itself (ideally with a tick-box on the form which will hide/show in_race_comment as well).

Is this possible via `DataGridView`?

Many thanks!

```
Public tblForm As New DataTable

Private Sub PopulateForm(ByVal FormSQL As String)
cmdCommand = New Odbc.OdbcCommand(FormSQL, cnConn)
adpAdapter.SelectCommand = cmdCommand
tblForm.Clear()
adpAdapter.Fill(tblForm)
End Sub

Private Sub frmForm_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load


'mySQL Code to populate table
 Dim FormSQL As String = "Select b.runner_id, b.starting_price, b.finish_position, a.num_finishers, b.distance_behind_winner, b.official_rating, b.in_race_comment from historic_races as a inner join (select * from historic_runners where runner_id =" & tblHorses.Rows(nHorseTableRow).Item(0) & ") as b on a.race_id = b.race_id"

'Populate tblForm
 PopulateForm(FormSQL)

'Populate datagridview
 DataGridViewForm.DataSource = tblForm

 DataGridViewForm.AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.AllCells
 DataGridViewForm.AutoResizeColumns()


End Sub
```

Comment: I don't think that's possible with a `DataGridView` as it is; you would need to create your own grid or search for one of the many around the internet that offer that functionality.

Comment: How does that work with getting a different grid from the internet? How do you import a different grid into the project?

Comment: Once you download/install the component: open your project, add a reference to the DLL of that component, go to design mode of one of the forms, right-click the toolbox and click "Choose items..."; find the required component on the list (you might have to browse for the DLL file first) and mark it. It should then appear on the toolbox.

Comment: Is there anyway to put the comment onto the 2nd row by wrapping the text string or will it always stay in its current position?

Comment: Also what about using a treeview instead - will that work?

Comment: I've got another idea:

Comment: is is possible to manually create additional rows in the table just holding the comment and then add a check-box hiding/unhiding them?

Comment: you should check out DevExpress controls, they implement nested DataGridViews that have exactly this functionality by default

Comment: How do you install in vb2010 - do you need package installer?